# R mongolite: Arrays are loaded from mongo as columns with elements as data.frame

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I've been using `jsonlite` and I used to argument `simplifyDataFrame` in `fromJSON()` function. Is there something similar to this in `mongolite` package? For example using `handler` argument? I haven't find enough documentation for this method.

I have records similar to

```
json <- '{"list": [{"x": 1, "y": "a"},{"x": 2, "y": "b"}],"numeric": 1.2}'
```

When I load the records using `find()` function it creates data frame with two columns. The first column contains whole data frames as elements.

```
df <- m$find()
df$list[[1]]
#   x y
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
```

What I want is something like

```
json %>% fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = F) %>% as.data.frame.list
#   list.x list.y list.x.1 list.y.1 numeric
# 1      1      a        1        a     1.2
```

Is there a solution for that?

---

**Edit:**

I know that I can do it in a loop to convert the data frame into a list. Or convert the data into JSON format and then use the `fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = F)`. Both methods are too slow for the size of data I use. See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343993/r-vector-of-jsons-to-data-frame).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `m$iterate()$batch()` instead of `m$find()`. It gives the output you expect.

```
json <- '{"list": [{"x": 1, "y": "a"},{"x": 2, "y": "b"}],"numeric": 1.2}'
json %>% fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = F) %>% as.data.frame.list
  list.x list.y list.x.1 list.y.1 numeric
1      1      a        2        b     1.2
catch <- m$insert(json)
m$iterate()$batch() %>% as.data.frame.list
  list.x list.y list.x.1 list.y.1 numeric
1      1      a        2        b     1.2
```